# Asynchronous call is returned after onDestroy has been called

Tags: angular, observable

I have an asynchronous server call that is set up like this. The response to the call, sets up a timer to call itself again in 30 seconds. A problem arises if the user navigates away from the page. Even though this.stopTimer() has been called, if a response is returned after leaving the page, the loop just continues. How can I prevent the next this.startTimer() from being called aftern ngOnDestroy() has been called?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.doSomething();
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.stopTimer();
}

doSomething() {
         var me = this;

        this.stopTimer();
        this.service.getStuff().subscribe(
            (response: any) => {

                ...do stuff
                this.startTimer();

            }
        )
    }

startTimer() {
    var me = this;
    clearTimeout(me.timeoutHandle);
    me.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () {
        me.doSomething();
    }, 30000);
}

stopTimer() {
    var me = this;
    clearTimeout(me.timeoutHandle);
    me.timeoutHandle = null;
}
```

Comment: does the service.getStuff() completes after the onDestroy is called?

Comment: yes, it completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider this approach.

```js
destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit() {
  this.startPolling();
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}

startPolling() {
  this.service.getStuff().pipe(
    tap(response => {
      //... do stuff
    }),
    delay(30 * 1000),  // wait for 30s before retry
    repeat(),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Note that in this case, if backend takes some time to return response, delay of 30s will start since response is received.

Observable `destroy$` offers you the capability to cancel the polling due to a user action or when component is destroyed.

Comment: Cool thanks. This works for this scenario, but I have a few scenarios that are using a forkJoin instead of a single call. I was able to use what you gave me to figure it out though.